# Как с помощью BeautifulSoup4 достать нужную информацию?

Tags: html, python, beautiful-soup

Всем привет! Недавно начал изучать питон и захотел сделать небольшой проект с выводом текущего курса валют. Недолго поискав, наткнулся на BeautifulSoup4 - начал читать документацию и... И фраза "Смотрю в книгу вижу фигу" лучше всего описывает мое понимание. Где-то на этом моменте я полностью теряюсь и действую методом тыка.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request


sauce = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.finanz.ru/valyuty/v-realnom-vremeni').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lmxl')
```

Собственно задача вытянуть [отсюда](http://www.finanz.ru/valyuty/v-realnom-vremeni) курс валют на доллар, но у меня возникает непонимание происходящего, после того, как я вижу этот непонятно поставленный тег  и кучу классов.

Стыдно просить помощи на такое, так как ответ, скорее всего, лежит на поверхности, но у меня не получается его найти. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Случайно ставил в "request" лишний символ, извиняюсь.

Comment: Т.е. проблемы уже нету ?

Comment: Нет, проблема все еще осталась. Пока писал сообщение случайно вставил символ в код.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как на счет альтернативного пути парсинга информации?

```
import pandas as pd

# разбираем HTML таблицы и берём вторую, тип Pandas.DataFrame
df = pd.read_html('http://www.finanz.ru/valyuty/v-realnom-vremeni', encoding='utf-8')[1] \
       .dropna(axis=1)

# фильтруем DF: выбираем только те строки, где вторая колонка `df[1]`
# подходит под регулярку: '^USD\/' (все строки, начинающиеся с 'USD/') 
print(df.loc[df[1].str.contains(r'^USD\/')])
```

Вывод:

```
In [238]: print(df.loc[df[1].str.contains(r'^USD\/')])
          1        2  3        4       5       6         7
3   USD/RUB   599125  -   599903  -0,13%  -00778  17:32:00
13  USD/EUR    08507  -    08477   0,36%   00030  17:33:00
14  USD/GBP    07711  -    07671   0,52%   00040  17:32:00
15  USD/JPY  1105840  -  1107710  -0,17%  -01870  17:32:00
16  USD/CHF    09750  -    09729   0,22%   00021  17:32:00
31  USD/CHF    09750  -    09729   0,22%   00021  17:32:00
34  USD/UAH   257150  -   257650  -0,19%  -00500  17:31:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlwt

# Парсинг курса $ US с сайта ЦБ РФ
def cbr_parse(sdate, edate):
    base_url = "https://www.cbr.ru/currency_base/dynamics/"
    params = "?UniDbQuery.Posted=True&UniDbQuery.mode=1&UniDbQuery.date_req1=&UniDbQuery.date_req2=&UniDbQuery.VAL_NM_RQ=R01235"
    q_from = "&UniDbQuery.FromDate="
    q_to = "&UniDbQuery.ToDate="
    sl = []
    response = urlopen(base_url + params + q_from + sdate + q_to + edate )
    if response.getcode() == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(str(response.read().decode('utf-8')), 'html.parser')
        tit = soup.body.find('h2', attrs={'class':'after_pf'})
        if tit != None:
            s = str(BeautifulSoup(str(tit), 'html.parser').get_text())
            s = s[s.index('Динамика'):].strip()
            print(s + '\nДата         Ед.   Курс')
            sl = [s, 'Дата', 'Ед.', 'Курс']
            tab = soup.body.find('table', attrs={'class':'data'})
            if tab != None:
                trlist = tab.findAll('tr')
                if trlist != None:
                    for tr in trlist:
                        t = BeautifulSoup(str(tr), 'html.parser')
                        tdlist = t.findAll('td')
                        if (tdlist != None) and (len(tdlist) == 3):
                            for td in tdlist:
                                s = str(BeautifulSoup(str(td), 'html.parser').get_text())
                                sl.append(s)
                    for i in range(4, len(sl)-2, 3):
                        print(sl[i] + '    ' + sl[i+1] + '    ' + sl[i+2])
        else:
            print("ERROR")
    return sl

# Основная программа
startdate = input('Введите начальную дату в формате <дд.мм.гггг>: ')
enddate = input('Введите конечную дату в формате <дд.мм.гггг>: ')
cells = cbr_parse(startdate, enddate)
s = cells[0][22:]
wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet(s)
ws.write(0, 0, cells[0])
k = 1
for i in range(1, len(cells)//3 + 1):
    for j in range(3):
        ws.write(i, j, cells[k + j])
    k += 3
wb.save(s + ".xls")
```

Результат дополнительно записывается в файл Доллар США.xls

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю точно как работать с таблицами, но обычный текст из блоков, удавалось выуживать так:

`tag = soup.find("div", class_ = "text")
 text = str(tag)`

Возможно, поможет.
Также убирать лишние теги можно так:

```
tag.div.decompose() # убираем вложенный div
tag.p.decompose()  # убираем текст в теге <p>
tag.br.decompose() # убираем перенос <br>
```